# scrollbar in a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice with expanded option (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony1, scrollbar, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to have a scrollbar on sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice with expanded => true ?
Thanks in advance.
I did this but didn't work:

```
... = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 
'Something','expanded' => true),array('style' => 'height: 200px'));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about limiting the height of the select box with css?

Answer (score 0):

Do it into your template: you can put your widget into a div with a fixed height and the overflow prop to auto:

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow:auto">
   <?php echo $form['myChoice']->render() ?>
</div>
```